# How to display date in user entered format in angular table using gantt-tooltip attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display the date in the tooltip in month and day format(e.g. Sep 01) in the angular gantt table after using th code below.

I am getting the date in defeult format i.e. "MMM DD, HH:mm" Please help me resolve this

`<gantt-tooltips enabled="true" date-format = "MMM DD"><gantt-tooltips/>`

Comment: Where is "th code below"? Did you forget to paste it?

Comment: i have also tried with this code line in the HTML file in the div <gantt-tooltips enabled="true" date-format = "moment().format("MMM DD");"><gantt-tooltips/>

Comment: <gantt-tooltips enabled="true" date-format = "'MMM DD'"><gantt-tooltips/>
this works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here looking for an answer, it is explained in https://www.angular-gantt.com/plugins/tooltips/:

> date-format:
>
> Format of the dates displayed in tooltip.
>
> See momentJS#format()
>
> default: MMM DD, HH:mm

And you can use it like:

```
<gantt-tooltips enabled="true" date-format = "'MMM DD'"><gantt-tooltips/>
```